# Sencha extJs/extreact 6/7 Tree get selected records

Tags: extreact

I have this `Tree` in ExtJs that allows for multiple selection:

```
<Tree
    ref={this.treeRef}
    flex={1}
    store={this.treeStore}
    selectable={{
        mode: 'multi',
        rows: true,
        drag: true,
}}/>
```

My problem is the fact that I cannot get the selected records. If I run [`getSelection`](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.0.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html#method-getSelection) it will return the **last element selected**/**a single element**.

How does one get all the selected elements in a tree? I found nothing in their docs and, of course, their forums are long dead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `Tree` has an undocumented method `getSelected()` which contains the selected items.

Comment: seems like a bug: should come from documented here:
https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.0.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html#method-getSelection as you suggested